# How to access internet my app app is minimized on Android Mi4i phone?

Tags: android

OS moving network state to BLOCKED, Whenever minimized the app.
Is there any steps to request for allow to access the internet, without move app to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Since the app is minimized and you want to perform network operations, go for a background service. It would keep running in the background and perform the network operations for you.

See this page for the steps to create a background service. 
[Android Official: Create background service](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

Comment: I am using services, but still same issue is there. GCM messages are reaching and device device also passing to APP, but OS is blocking network for APP.

Comment: Finally I found why, in Mi4i there is a setting enable and disable data when app background. If i enable then it is fine. Now i want to know how to enable for my app programmatically? because i observed default enable background data access for some apps like WhatsApp. How can I do?